# Unexpected behavior from MaxValue and Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

consider the following function

```
α = 1/Sqrt[(1 - η^2)^2 + 4 D0^2 η^2];
p1 = Plot[{Evaluate[Table[α, {D0, 0, 1, .1}]], 1/(1 + η^2)}, {η, 0, 2}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

i now wanted to calculate the function that goes through all the maxima of this function for $\eta \in(0,1)$.

Using

```
MaxValue[α, D0]
```

gives

[image]

while

```
Maximize[α, D0]
```

yields

[image]

which are both not what I'm looking for. Using the straight forward approach

```
max = α /. Solve[D[α, η] == 0]
```

[image]

```
p2 = Plot[max[[1]], {η, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}]
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

it works. I guess i didn't quite get how `MaxValue` works. Can someone teach me, what I did wrong?

Comment: You can also get all the maxima with `Maximize[\[Alpha], D0]`. And from the docs of `MaxValue` under Details and Options: "`MaxValue[\[Ellipsis]]` is effectively equivalent to `First[Maximize[\[Ellipsis]]]`." That explains it.

Comment: I used that too but the correct solution is not under the given results

Comment: The behavior you show suggests that `D0` has been given a value somewhere at top-level in notebook. If so, that is source of your trouble.

Comment: I checked and `D0` hasn't been given any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if this is entirely not what you were asking but your final line:

> I guess i didn't quite get how `MaxValue` works. Can someone teach me, what I did wrong?

suggests that perhaps an example of MaxValue doing something, anything, useful might help.

```
mv = MaxValue[α, η];

p3 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[mv, {D0, 0, 1, .1}]], {η, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}]

Show[p1, p3]
```

[image]

So `MaxValue` quite handily gives is the maximum value that is reached for each value of `D0`.

Likewise `MaxValue[α, D0]` gives us the maximum value that is reached for each value of `η`, which is the uppermost line in the plot:

```
mv2 = MaxValue[α, D0]

p4 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[mv2, {D0, 0, 1, .1}]], {η, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}]

Show[p1, p4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I guess my attempt to do this using `MaxValue` was doomed to fail